# Hosting helloworld project to cvs

Tags: cvs

i have written a programme like helloworld, is there any way i can commit project like it to a CVS server?
  It seems the project approved must meet some requirements, so i think the chance is tiny.
Is there existing CVS server which allow beginners to host their "simple" project free.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your aim is to get used to [source control systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_control), then just use your own PC as a local CVS server. It's not hard.

Also, CVS is outdated and has problems. I recommend SVN instead. [Here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/setting-up-subversion-on-windows.html)'s a guide to setting up SVN locally on Windows.

Comment: If you are hosting the repository on the local machine I really (x5) recommend using Mercurial (eg.).

Comment: @mbanzon: Why, what's special about Mercurial?

Comment: the guide is for windows but i am using linux. Anyway thank you . Now i want to try mercurial, can it be integrated with eclipse ?

Comment: In my personal work I prefer Mercurial because it gives me the posibility to clone and branch projects very easilly across multiply machines or on a single machine as I like.

Answer (score 2):

You can host your own CVS server - which would make it free.

But now you are at it - why CVS? Personally I switched to Subversion a long time ago and then recently switched to Mercurial. imho any distributed version control system would do.

Is CVS some sort of requirement or just what you stumbled uppon first?

Comment: i meant that the approved project must abide by the requirements of the CVS server,which is sometimes not feasible for beginners.